# First Order Logic - coming up with an example

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm learning First order logic using a university textbook and it has the following question:

> Give an example of languages $L'$ and $L$, $L \subseteq L'$, as well
>   as formulas $A$ and $B$ in language $L'$ such that for every set of
>   formulas $T$ in $L$:
>
> If $T \vdash A$ then $T \vdash B$
>
> **But** there exists a set of formulas $T'$ in $L$ such that $T' \cup \{A\} \nvdash B$

Ok I have been staring at this question for over 2 hours with no major breakthroughs, just trying to run different examples in my head. I just can't seem to find an example that if you can infer A and B from T then you can't infer B from T and A.

Any hints or help is appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Is $T'$ supposed to be a set of formulas in language $L$ or in language $L'$? Furthermore: what is the exact problem? Is it "Given $L,L',A,B$ with these properties, show that there exists such a $T'$."?

Comment: Ah thank you, I fixed the details above. Yes $T'$ is supposed to be in $L$. We are supposed to give everything, that is: $L, L', T'$ and $A, B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are working in first-order logic with equality built in, take $L$ to have no non-logical symbols. Take $L'$ to be $L$ extended with two constant symbols $c$ and $d$. Finally, take $A$ to be $c = d$ and $B$ to be $\forall x\cdot\forall y \cdot x = y$. Then if $T \subseteq L$ and $T \vdash A$, then $T \vdash B$, but with $T' = \emptyset$, $T' \cup \{A\} \not\vdash B$.

If you don't want to use equality, take $L$ to have a single unary predicate symbol $p$ and no other non-logical symbols and take $L'$ to extend $L$ by adding a constant symbol $c$. Then take $A$ to be $p(c)$ and $B$ to be $\forall x \cdot p(x)$.

Comment: Ah I see now, nice simple example. It seems I was over-thinking it a bit :) Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

> I just can't seem to find an example that if you can infer A and B from T then you can't infer B from T and A.

That's because there can't be such an example. If $T \vdash A \land B$, then $T \vdash B$, and therefore $T, A \vdash B$, in any standard logic.

As to the displayed problem you reproduce(?), should the last $T$ be $T'$? What's the relation between $T$ and $T'$? If there are no constraints, just take $T'$ to be the empty set!

Comment: Taking $T'$ to be the empty set is not enough! Consider the case where $L = L'$ and put $T' = \emptyset$. Then for $T = \{A\}$, it clearly is $T\vdash A$, and so $T \vdash B$. And with $T = \{A\} = \emptyset\cup\{A\} = T'\cup \{A\}$ we have $T' \cup \{ A \} \vdash B$ as well!

Comment: I edited the post above - fixed the last sentence, seems I misread the question. $T'$ is different than $T$. The way I understood it was to give 2 languages, one richer than the other (but also contains the smaller language in it). Then choose two formulas in $L'$ such that you can infer either A or B from any group of formulas in $L$ (but with the constraint that if you can infer A then you can infer B) but there exists some group of formulas such that you cannot infer both of them together.